# Java Spring RestTemplate enforce HTTPS

Tags: java, client, protocols, selection, resttemplate

Is there a way to enforce usage of HTTPS protocol, i.e. disable usage of plain HTTP protocol within the RestTemplate client in Spring?

I have this client as an abstract class and there are numerous implementations using it. So filtering input parameters for URI protocol http is not such a good idea.

Is there a way to achieve this using `ClientHttpRequestFactory` or similar?

Thank you,

Josef

Answer (score 0):

It's not about Spring. You just should configure your container or server(Tomcat, JBoss, i.e.)

Comment: What if I want to limit accessing remote addresses, which I don't control?